# Given a projective $R$-module $M$, how does one find another $R$-module $N$ such that $M \oplus N$ is a free $R$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

Given a projective $R$-module $M$, how does one find another $R$-module $N$ such that $M \oplus N$ is a free $R$-module?

> In my case, $R = {\mathbb{C}[x, y]}/{(y^2 - x^3 + x)}$, and $M$ is the ideal generated by $\{x, y\}$ over $R$. Since $M$ is projective I know such $N$ exists, but how do I find it?

Here is my initial attempt at solving this.

Since $M$ is generated by $\{x, y\}$, we have a function $F$ (the identity function) from $\{x, y\}$ to $M$, by universal property of free modules, we have a map $G$ from $R^2$ to $M$, and since $M$ is generated by $\{x, y\}$, $G$ is surjective. Further more, in a previous question we proved that $M \oplus \ker(G)$ is isomorphic to $R^2$, so I assumed one must find $\ker(G)$, but can't see how this could be done.

Second edit:
Tried continuing in this direction, here's what I got so far.
By definition, we must have $G((1,0))=x$ and $G((0,1))=y$ or vise versa ("G maps generators to generators"). If we defines $G(( f(x,y), g(x,y)))=x*f((x,y))+y*g((x,y))$ then we can show that G is indeed a surjective map, and by the uniqueness of G, we get that G must be as we defined it to be.
Now all that is left is to find a description of KER($G$) in terms of $R^2$

Comment: Did you try to find an answer for this question yourself? If yes, please show us your findings. Where were you stuck? Where is this problem from? Why is it interesting and important? Unfortunately, “solve this for me” questions are usually quickly get downvoted and closed on this site.

Comment: Sorry, taking a course in commutative algebra, this was a question in our homework. I'll edit the main post and add my attempt at solving, though I'm not sure it's the right way to approach this.

Comment: If you are someone who downvoted this post due to missing content and that content has been added, please remove your downvote to improve the site.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! Is this from an exercise? In general I'd say "take $N = \ker G$" is a pretty satisfactory answer. If it isn't, can you explain why? What does "find" mean? Do you just want a more explicit description? If so, what's wrong with just writing out explicitly what it means to belong to the kernel of $G$?

Comment: Let me denote the basis elements of $R^2$ by $e_1$ and $e_2$. Then the map $G$ is given by $e_1\mapsto x$ and $e_2\mapsto y$. Notice that $-ye_1+xe_2\mapsto 0$. Similarly, $(x^2-1)e_1-ye_2\mapsto 0$. My guess is that $\ker G=\langle -ye_1+xe_2,(x^2-1)e_1-ye_2\rangle\subseteq R^2$.